# JSON.stringify replacer not working as expected (keep properties where name starts with)

Tags: javascript, stringify

I want to keep all property names that start with a certain string and remove all others from an object.

Why is the following not working - keep property `foo` only - and why does the opposite work? ([test it here](https://runjs.co/s/ybh2X4euf)):

```js
const o = {
  foo: 1,
  bar: 2,
  baz: 3
};
console.log(JSON.stringify(o, (k, v) => k.startsWith('f') ? v : undefined)); // undefined -> why not {"foo":1} ?
console.log(JSON.stringify(o, (k, v) => !k.startsWith('f') ? undefined : v)); // undefined -> why not {"foo":1} ?
console.log(JSON.stringify(o, (k, v) => !k.startsWith('f') ? v : undefined)); // {"bar":2,"baz":3}

Object.keys(o).forEach(key => {
  console.log(key, key.startsWith('f'));
});
// foo,true
// bar,false
// baz,false
```

Comment: The replacer function probably doesn't work the way you think it does. `k` will be an empty string, and `v` is the initial `o` object. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify#the_replacer_parameter

Comment: (At least initially)

Comment: For the initial empty key, you need to directly return `v` again - https://jsfiddle.net/w02tr1vz/

Comment: Also to keep in mind, just checking for `k==""` might not always suffice - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify#using_a_function_as_replacer: _"If you wish the replacer to distinguish an initial object from a key with an empty string property (since both would give the empty string as key and potentially an object as value), you will have to keep track of the iteration count (if it is beyond the first iteration, it is a genuine empty string key)."_

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reading the [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify) of `JSON.stringify`

> The replacer function is called for the initial object being stringified as well, in which case the key is an empty string ("").

And in your first two calls of JSON stringify, you return `undefined` when the `key` does not start with `f` (which is obviously the case, when `key == ""`). And so if the replacer for the initial object returns `undefined`, of course the result the whole stringification is `undefined`

```js
let o = { foo: 3, bar: 4, baz: 5}
let s = JSON.stringify(o, (key, value) => !key 
  ? value 
  : key.startsWith("f") ? value : undefined);
console.log(s);
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to handle the empty key passed to the replacer function.

According to the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify#the_replacer_parameter),

> The replacer function is called for the initial object being stringified as well, in which case the key is an empty string (""). It is then called for each property on the object or array being stringified. Array indices will be provided in its string form as key. The current property value will be replaced with the replacer's return value for stringification.

So that when you return an `undefined` value for the first entry, the stringified result is `undefined`.

```js
const o = {foo:1,bar:2,baz:3};

console.log(
  `// {"foo":1}`, 
  JSON.stringify(o, (k,v) => k.startsWith('f') || k == "" ? v : undefined)
); 
console.log(
  `// {"foo":1}`, 
  JSON.stringify(o, (k,v) => !k.startsWith('f') && k != "" ? undefined: v)
);
    
console.log(
  `// {"bar":2,"baz":3}`,
  JSON.stringify(o, (k,v) => !k.startsWith('f') ? v : undefined)
);
```

Comment: Thank you, I missed this tiny but important piece of the docs.